# Visiting Formula 1 Monaco GP on a tight budget

Tags: budget, france, events, monaco, formula-one

Racing is in my blood. I love Formula 1 and I have already watched live races in Germany and Belgium. But I'm dreaming of the Monte Carlo GP.

The problem is - MONEY. So what's gonna be the cheapest way to see the Grand Prix weekend (Sa. + Sun.) live? The tickets are expensive enough (about € 1000 for 3 persons on the tribunes).

I think we will drive by car, flight tickets are too expensive on the race weekend. So we are looking for a hotel/hostel <100km from Monaco. Must we drive with the car to the circuit or is there a possibility to go by train or bus?

Comment: It is worth noting that this is the most crowded week-end of the year on the french riviera: Monte Carlo GP takes place at the same time as the Cannes film festival.

Comment: Yes, I know, but... F1 weekends are always very crowded :) The problem is that the airlines and the hotels are getting more expensive, and Monaco is already very expensive

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Along the coast, there are trains, for example from Nice and area. The area is not that cheap either, but you can still try. [The "ter" SNCF site has a map](http://www.ter-sncf.com/Regions/paca/Fr/Se_deplacer_en_TER/Avant_mon_voyage/Plan_de_ligne/Carte_Flash.aspx), and lists a [train line along the coast](http://telechargement.ter-sncf.com/Images/Paca/Tridion/FH04-Mandelieu-Grasse-Ventimiglia_v5_tcm-27-72969.pdf) until Cannes, which has pretty frequent trains.
Prices are around 5-10 euros each way I would say.

There are also buses that are cheaper. On [the `cg06.fr` site of the Conseil Général des Alpes Maritimes](http://www.cg06.fr/fr/servir-les-habitants/deplacements/transport-collectifs/lignes-et-horaires/lignes-et-horaires/) it says the bus lines to Monaco are 100 and 100X, tickets are 1 euro each way.

By the way Nice is very nice city, worth visiting.

EDIT: I don't know how far the station is from the GP though, but I guess it's close enough (Monaco is not that big and stations are usually located downtown)

Comment: There are hostels in Nice, and also in the even nicer Cannes, not so far away. Out of season these can be pretty cheap but it wouldn't surprise me if the prices go up for the formula one, and get booked out way in advance. I had the impression that when you come above ground from the station that you were pretty much in part of the harbour area and that part of the circuit goes right through that area. I could be wrong though since it was just a few hours over a decade ago,

Comment: yeah and to add up to @hippietrail comment, when you book hostel/hotel, pay attention to how far the station is. In this area they can easily be out of town

Comment: +1 for staying in Nice—there are many hostels and [getting to Monaco](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11066/how-to-get-from-nice-to-monaco-by-public-transport) is indeed very easy and cheap. But do book your accommodation way in advance for the GP weekend!

Answer (score 2):

As other replies say, there are Trains from wherever you stay to Monaco and is quite cheap.
If you are on a budget you have some different possibilities and I'd suggest what I'd do in a budget:

- Get general entrance tickets. You still have a great view and you'll join and enjoy the Grand Prix. I believe with that ticket you can also enjoy Monaco's Castle terrace views. There is personal working and checking your tickets so you can not get in for free, but if you have a general admission ticket you can get in. There is more room than in the General Admission spot, yet I'd suggest you to be there early morning every day to get a good spot no matter where you go. Views are okay and from the castle you can track the cars almost the whole way from the pool section to the end of the straight line and some more.

To me, the Castle View is quite a good view giving the case that we are speaking about a Urban City racetrack so you know you won't see as much as in a regular permanent racetrack no matter where you do place yourself.

- Try to contact a Track Marshal from the Grand Prix. I did that 3 years ago and bought my tickets through him. I got 3 days tickets for the Pool section grandstand for 300€ cheaper than usual prices. I payed 500€ instead of 800€. (yes, I know it is still a lot of money). They do have some % discount and so you can just ask some of them to help you purchase cheaper tickets.

Those are my main options being on a budget. Might be others but those are the ones I know. Of course you can also go and enjoy the atmosphere of the Grand Prix not having any tickets nor view of the races, but can be quite frustrating.

Comment: I attended the race in Monaco 4 years ago and on Sunday we were in the general admission area and I would say it's the worst general admission area in the whole F1 calendar - not enough place, way too many people and too far from the circuit. The best option is the Z1 - not too expensive and only 1-2m from the cars.

Comment: I do agree with you but is a place where to watch the race. As everything in life, if you are there early morning you would have a good spot.
I believe that with your general admission ticket you can also go to the top terrace of the Monaco Castle (there is personal checking your tickets to allow you to get in and out from there) and have some space and views for yourself if you don't like the general admission spot.

The one thing I'd reccomend if you buy a general admission ticket is to be early morning, to have a decent view. (like you'll do for example going to a Rally).